# Method returns unit instead of string in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to get the string out of the `Set` type in Scala. However, no matter what I try it is returning `Unit` as a return type instead of a `string`.

```
if (!validationMessages.isEmpty) {
      dataTuple = (parsedJson.toString(), for (s <- validationMessages.toString()){
        s.toString()
      })
      println(dataTuple)
    }
    else {
      dataTuple = (parsedJson.toString(), "some string...")
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to return a tuple like `(String, String)`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The value of a block is the value of the last expression in the block. In this case the value of the `if` part is

```
println(dataTuple)
```

and the value of the `else` part is

```
dataTuple = (parsedJson.toString(), "some string...")
```

Both of these expressions return `Unit` so the result is `Unit`.

The quick fix is to make `dataTuple` the last statement in each branch:

```
if (!validationMessages.isEmpty) {
      dataTuple = (parsedJson.toString(), for (s <- validationMessages.toString()){
        s.toString()
      })
      println(dataTuple)
      dataTuple
    } else {
      dataTuple = (parsedJson.toString(), "some string...")

      dataTuple
    }
```

But also consider something like this as a simpler solution:

```
val msg = 
    if (validationMessages.nonEmpty) {
       validationMessages.mkString(", ")
    } else {
       "some string"
    }
(parsedJson.toString, msg)
```

---

The `mkString` is an attempt to replace this code:

```
for (s <- validationMessages.toString()) {
  s.toString()
}
```

This code appears to be trying to create a string by combining all the validation messages, but it actually returns `Unit` because the `for` does not have a `yield`. `mkString` calls `toString` on each element of the `Set` and then creates a string by putting ", " between each element. This seems to be roughly what is wanted and should be easy to modify to the actual requirement.

Comment: I didn't get the `mkString()` part

Comment: I've added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Why is the code behaving like this?**

That code has return type `Unit`, because that is the return type of both branches of the `if` statement.

The `if` branch ends with `println(dataTuple)`, which returns `Unit`.
The `else` branch ends with `dataTuple = ...`, which is variable assignment, which returns `Unit`. If you wanted it to *return* the tuple stored in `dataTuple`, you'd just have to add `dataTuple` to the end.

**What do you probably want to do instead?**

```
(parsedJson.toString, validationMessages.mkString("[", ", ", "]"))
```

That will return a tuple containing first `parsedJson` as a string, and second, each element of `validationMessages`, in arbitrary order (because `Set` is unordered), starting with `[`, with a `,`  between consecutive elements, and `]` at the end.

So if `parsedJson` was `{"key1": "value1"}` and `validationMessages` was `Set("unexpected key: key1", "missing key: key0")` this would return `("{"key1":"value1"}",["unexpected key: key1", "missing key: key0"]`.

If you don't want to put something special at the beginning/end of your `.mkString`, you can call it with only the middle argument (the delimiter).

If `validationMessages` is empty, then `validationMessages.mkString("delimiter")` returns an empty string, and `validationMessages.mkString("start", "delimiter", "end")` returns `"startend"`.

One of the beautiful things about scala is how you can do complex things in a single line (as long as you know the language well enough).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @mbbush. I accepted Tim's answer as he answered first. Much appreciated though (y)